# Testing using spring boot throws null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am new to spring boot and i am trying to test a very simple class. But when i run the `testMe()` below I get exception below

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MyTest.testMe(MyTest.java:25)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
```

My understanding is when the context is loaded all the beans are initialized and object `HelloWorld` is created and are autowired in `MyTest` call. But `helloWorld` object is `null` at line  `helloWorld.printHelloWorld();`

I need assistance here to understand what is missing.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {AppConfigTest.class})
public class MyTest {

    @Mock
    @Autowired
    private Message myMessage;

    @Autowired
    private HelloWorld helloWorld;

    @Test
    public void testMe(){
       helloWorld.printHelloWorld();
    }
}


@Configuration
public class AppConfigTest {

   @Bean
    public HelloWorld helloWorld() {
        return new HelloWorldImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public Message getMessage(){
        return new Message("Hello");
    }
}

public interface HelloWorld {
    void printHelloWorld();
}

public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {

    @Autowired
    Message myMessage;

    @Override
    public void printHelloWorld() {
        System.out.println("Hello : " + myMessage.msg);
    }

}

public class Message {

    String msg;

    Message(String message){
        this.msg = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Clearly helloWorld object is null.  Check your assumptions.  A spin through a debugger will help.  Put a breakpoint in the creation method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're running your tests with a runner that's not Spring-aware, so no wiring is happening. Look at the [Spring Boot testing documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html), all their examples use `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`. To mock a bean, annotate it with `@MockBean`, not `@Mock`. Make sure that the `spring-boot-starter-test` is included in your POM.